# writing files to windows partitions from linux

Tags: linux

I have a linux based device (embedded linux) and I want to download the file and store it in windows partition. Please suggest how to do it with a shell script or any other way.

Comment: Which file do you want to download? And where from?

Comment: It could be any file from http server. I am using wget to download file but it is saving on my linux based device and I want to store it on windows partition (any drive C,D....)

Answer (score 0):

First you're going to need support for the "windows" file system.  I assume that is NTFS, but could be FAT32.  Either way your "embedded linux" may not have the right module.  But once you have the module all you have to do is mount it like any other file system.

This [site](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/) might be helpful. But it just depends on the specifics of your 2 environments.